Asian movie where a girl commits suicide jumping off the window (art cinema)
Hope someone can help me. I remember not much but I will tell everything I can recall. It was obviously Asian, I watched it on a cultural public channel (which means it's an art cinema) 5 years ago, I can tell by the quality of the video that it was filmed between 2002 to 2010. Basically I remember pretty well one scene in particular:
A teen girl (15-20 years old) standing inside a room of a floor in a multi familiar building. The camera shows just the girl standing, she has only underwear on. the camera just stands showing the girl some seconds, then she seems to be staring at the window of the room she is. After a while she starts to walk at the window and then starts climbing it. 
The next take shows her from outside, standing in the window frame and looking down to the street. The next take shows her from above in the floor with pretty much blood around her body. The scene was very calm, I don't recall any music or a word by the girl. I think that scene lasted less than a minute. The building was modest and the street where the girl falls is paved with some cars parked there.
That's the only thing I recall exactly, the other thing I vaguely recall is a scene of something that seems to be a room where kids/teens sleep in an orphanage, Im not even sure if I have seen it in the same movie. 

Strangely enough, I believe this scene is from a movie that I identified with the help of this site in just the last month.
There is a scene exactly like the one you describe in the 2005 Mongolian movie Season of the Horse. Here's an article about the movie and its maker, and here's a review in Variety. 
The context of the scene is that the girl has been forced to relocate from her rural home to an urban encampment, as part of a government's attempt at social engineering. 
Unfortunately, neither I nor the expert researcher who answered my question have been able to locate any scenes online, so I am unable to provide video proof right now.

Oh, thanks! It could be, I will ask the channel staff where I watched it. A shame there are just few images on the english speaking web. I will contact the channel and see if they can provide me the video.

Thank you very much, finally I found the movie, it ended being the Korean  movie "Samaritan Girl" by Kim Ki-duk. I really appreciate your care :)

You're welcome! I'm glad you found the movie.

If it's possible you've combined the memory of two similar scenes I'll take a long-shot guess.
It reminds me of both Babel and Lethal Weapon.
In Babel a Japanese woman contemplates suicide at a window or balcony but I don't recall her actually jumping.
In the opening scene of Lethal Weapon a young blonde woman jumps from a balcony and her fall is shown. I recall it being a calm, quiet scene.

I watched Babel and yes that scene is alike but she doesn't commit, the other movie really has nothing to do with this. I appreciate it, thank you!
